# Получаю ошибку A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 409 когда пытаюсь запустить бота на сервере

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Я написал телеграм бота на питоне, задеплоил его на VPS от Reg.ru
Когда запускаю бота, получаю следующую ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда запустил в первый раз выбило ошибку, но я воспользовался следующим скриптом(увидел на каком-то сайте, что бы бот сам запускался после рестарта серверов телеграма):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Бот запустился и работал, после чего я нажал на кнопку, после нажатия на которую выбивает ошибку. После этого я пробовал разными способами его запускать, так и не запустился.
Возможно кто-то знает в чем причина. Буду благодарен за ответ
P.S. На этом токене запущен только этот бот

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Answer (score 1):

Данный конфликт возникает, когда бот с определенным токеном запускается на двух хостах одновременно. Возможно вы запустили скрипт на рабочем ПК в IDE и затем, не закончив выполнение, запустили его на VPS. Убедитесь, что бот запущен только на одной машине.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка 409 возникает в том случае, если нет доступа к боту, и причина этого может быть в том, что бот запущен/задеплоен/доступен на другом хосте.

**Решение:**

1. Убрать доступность бота на хостигне
2. Изменить токен бота